# How does ConcurrentSkipListMap's lastEntry() method work?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I'm using ConcurrentSkipListMap object (Java) and need to access the last entry. The API does offer a lastEntry() method.
Now let say that I am getting the value of the the last entry of the map that way:

```
MyValueClass myValue = myConcurrentMap.lastEntry().getValue();
```

At some later point, some other thread puts in the map a new entry.

```
myConcurrentMap.put(key, value);
```

What happens now to the myValue object I got earlier from the map? Does it keep reference to the object in the last entry at the time I got it from the map, or it keeps recalculating the last entry of the map and changes the reference accordingly?

Comment: Are you asking about thread safety or the basic working of references in Java? Your title claims the first, but your post shows that you don't really understand how references work.

Comment: I will edit my title, what I want to know is what will happen in the scenario I've described

Comment: Once retrieved, it will stay the same. Think of the consequences if it were as you suggest. You could never be sure if your reference is still the one you retrieved from a collection. Nightmare!

Comment: if you retrieve last value again then you must have new value .

Comment: It's how all references work, no matter where you retrieve them. They can't change the object they point to without explicit reassignment. If they point to a mutable object, the object's properties can change, but it'll still be the same object.